# Olympic medalist in both the Summer and Winter Olympics

Tags: history, trivia, olympics

Has anyone ever won Olympic medals in both the Summer and Winter Olympics?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are six people that have won medals in both the Summer and Winter Olympic Games.

- [Gillis Grafström](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillis_Grafstr%C3%B6m) of Sweden is the most successful figure skater in Olympic history, having won 3 gold medals and 1 silver medal in 1920-1932.  However, he is only on this list because in 1920, there was no Winter Olympics, and figure skating was an event in the Summer Games.  The first Winter Games was in 1924, where he got his second gold.
- [Eddie Eagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Eagan) was an American gold medalist in boxing in 1920.  He failed to medal in 1924, but in 1932 he was a member of the bobsleigh team which took gold, making him the first person to win a medal in Summer and Winter for different events.
- [Jacob Tullin Thams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Tullin_Thams) of Norway won the first Olympic gold medal for ski jumping in 1924.  In 1936, he was on the sailing team that won silver in the 8-metre class.
- [Christa Luding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christa_Luding) of Germany is a speed skater and cyclist.  She won medals in skating from 1984-1992, and in 1988 with her silver medal in track cycling became the only person to win a medal in the Winter and Summer Games in the same year.
- [Clara Hughes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clara_Hughes) of Canada is also a cyclist and speed skater.  She won two bronze medals for cycling in 1996, and won four medals for skating between 2002-2010.  She has the distinction of being the only person to have won multiple medals in both the Summer and Winter Games.
- [Lauryn Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauryn_Williams) of the USA won a silver medal at Athens 2004 and gold in London 2012 as a sprinter.  This year at Sochi 2014, she won silver in bobsleigh.